# Created a custom CSS class, want to change the link hover color but it isn't working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to change the link hover color to #666666 on a specific set of links, so I have created a custom CSS class. However, the effect is not working. I have tried a few things, like nesting the class within a div tag, for example, but my current HTML and CSS are as follows. I am *VERY* new to code so any help is appreciated.

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
<a class="supportlinks" href="http://www.sharepointflex.org/pricing-plans/">
<span style="color: #3fa9f5; text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">Implementation Support</span></a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​</p>

.supportlinks:hover {color:#666666; text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: Looks like the CSS on your span is taking precedence.

Comment: there's gotta be a dupe of this somewhere

Comment: Inline css can't be overridden by the :hover pseudo-class, can it? Trying that out now and it seems to block it (once moved to the head element it works fine).

Comment: @DrewKennedy yes it can't be overridden unless you have !important on the style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an inline style on your `span`, so if you want to avoid the use of `!important`, which I recommend, you will have to get rid of the inline style.

I would also recommend moving the other inline declarations into your CSS as well, but the following example shows the minimum amount of refactoring to get it to work.

Here is a **Live Demo** that shows how you would pull the inline style out into a CSS rule:

```css
.supportlinks {color: #3fa9f5;}
.supportlinks:hover {color:#666666; text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">
<a class="supportlinks" href="http://www.sharepointflex.org/pricing-plans/">
<span style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">Implementation Support</span></a></p>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/f8dhtcz6/

Comment: you might as well move the text-align and font-size though i agree with your  solution

Comment: @Daemedeor I suggested that in the second paragraph of my answer, thanks though!

Comment: oh didn't see that :P

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response! This is my first time using Stack Overflow and you've helped make this a great experience for me. I have run into a bit of a problem though. Using a p style tag creates a large space above the text and I can't seem to figure out how to get the words "Implementation support" to center without creating this large space above the text. Do you have any suggestions or comments? I'm still learning and I appreciate your patience. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @Marlee It sounds to me like that would be best posted as a new question, that way we will have more space to diagnose the problem, and your question will get more exposure. Post a new question and then paste the link to it into a comment here. If it's relevant, you may also link to this question from your new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/uprhu09L/

Moved the color from your style to its own class

so now the classes are

```
.supportlinks{color: #3fa9f5;}
.supportlinks:hover {color:#666666; text-decoration:none;}
```

HTML is

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
<a class="supportlinks" href="http://www.sharepointflex.org/pricing-plans/">
<span style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">Implementation Support</span></a></p>
```

Comment: you might as well move the text-align and font-size then

Answer (score 0):

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <a class="supportlinks" href="http://www.sharepointflex.org/pricing-plans/">
    <span style="">Implementation Support</span>
  </a>
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​</p>

.supportlinks {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.supportlinks span {
  color: #3fa9f5;
  text-align: center; 
  font-size: 18px;
}
.supportlinks:hover span {
  color:#666666; 
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/bpr4p49f/)

1. You are trying to style anchor on hover, but an inline style to span child in anchor takes precedence.
2. I am not sure if span within an anchor is really useful here, but at your discretion.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! I very much appreciate it.