# I am trying to reduce the padding between an icon and text created in Visual Composer

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm not sure if I'm in the right place but I created part of a webpage using Visual Composer but I am having trouble figuring out how to reduce the padding between the icon and the title text below. Here is a link to how this section of the page currently looks: http://postimg.org/image/gv19ve3in/

I asked a question previously (Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423113/created-a-custom-css-class-want-to-change-the-link-hover-color-but-it-isnt-wor)) and found an answer that solved my problem. But now due to the P tag which I used to center the text I have created too much space between the icon and the text. I'm hoping someone will be able to help me figure out how to do this.

I am new to web development and new to Stack Overflow and still trying to learn how to navigate all this complexity. I am building this website in Wordpress and this specific element I am working on has been created with Visual Composer, however, you can see the code I used in the link to my previous question.

As always, thank you for your help.

Comment: please add some code, because otherwise we can't help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Created a custom CSS class, want to change the link hover color but it isn't working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423113/created-a-custom-css-class-want-to-change-the-link-hover-color-but-it-isnt-wor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since there is no code I can not tell you 100%

but you have 2 aproch

1- get the icons closer by

```
.icon-class { position:relative;bottom:-15px; }
```

or

```
.icon-class { margin-bottom:-15px; }
```

2- try to see the reason for the margin and reduce it

Comment: but if we have the code or link to your website will be much better

Comment: Thank you @J.Tural! I'm sorry for the lack of code, but based on what you told me, I created a custom css class within Visual Composer and added the code you suggested into the css file and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help.